# VMware Workstation 16.2.3 build-19376536 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: vmware, 22.04

Ive tried multiple fixes to get this to work.

Its driving me mad. At first VM ware wouldn't even load up. I had an issue with vmnet and Vmmon. I reinstalled the correct version because of a kernel issue apparently.

https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/archive/workstation-16.2.3.tar.gz

VMware now gets past the initial issue and loads into the application.

When I have made a VM and load it up I am faced with another issue:

1. Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory.
   Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded.
2. Failed to initialize monitor device.
3. Unable to change virtual machine power state: Transport (VMDB) error -14: Pipe connection has been broken.

The Never ending saga. I have been looking all over the net for a solution and nothing has helped so far. If anyone can help me it would be much appreciated.

I also tried this command:

- vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

Starting VMware services:

- Virtual machine monitor                                     **failed**
- Virtual machine communication interface                       **done**
- VM communication interface socket family                      **done**
- Virtual ethernet                                            **failed**
- VMware Authentication Daemon                                  **done**

Unable to start services

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
wget https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/archive/workstation-16.2.3.tar.gz
tar -xzf workstation-16.2.3.tar.gz
cd vmware-host-modules-workstation-16.2.3
tar -cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
sudo cp -v vmmon.tar vmnet.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

I had a problem with my VMware after updating OS, and I found these to solve my problem. Also other person write that these helped him run his VMware on Ubuntu 22.04.
[image]

Source:
[image: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VM-Workstation-16-1-gt-16-2-1-on-Ubuntu-21-10-broke-everything/m-p/2913449/highlight/false#M176158]
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VM-Workstation-16-1-gt-16-2-1-on-Ubuntu-21-10-broke-everything/m-p/2913449/highlight/false#M176158

Comment: Thank you! This worked.

Comment: After re-compile, it works.
Thank you very much

Comment: I did the steps above but also had to disable secure boot.